# pgfplots plot only odd 3d segments

Tags: pgfplots

Given a table of 3d coordinates like this:

```
x1 y1 z1  
x2 y2 z2  
x3 y3 z3  
x4 y4 z4
```

I would like in a single `\addplot3` command print the the segments that go from the 1st point to the 2nd point, the 3rd to the 4th and so on like this:

```
(x1, y1, z1)->(x2, y2, z2)
(x3, y3, z3)->(x4, y4, z4)
```

and not the segments that connect points 2 to 3, 4 to 5 etc etc.

How can I achieve that?

For the moment I'm stuck with this

[image: For the moment I'm stuck with this]

given by this code:

```
\documentclass[10pt, border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11,
             height=15cm
             }
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \begin{axis}[
            view={37}{30},
            xlabel = {$x_{lvlh}$ (km)}, ylabel = {$y_{lvlh}$ (km)}, zlabel = {$z_{lvlh}$ (km)},
            unit vector ratio=1 1 1,
            ymin=-0.15, ymax=0.15
            ]%
            \addplot3[
                blue,
            ]
            table [x={x1}, y={x2}, z={x3}] {statex.dat};

            \addplot3+[
                mark=*,
                black,
                mark size=0.85,
                error bars/y dir=plus,
            ]
            table [x={u1}, y={u2}, z={u3}] {u.dat};

        \end{axis}
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    \end{tikzpicture}%

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Do you have control over the data file format? In that case, you could simply add a blank line after every second line.

Comment: Yes I have control over the data file! It works! Wonderful, i would never thought this solution.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is solved in the comments.